# I'm trying to use group by with inner join in sql but it is generating an error

Tags: sql-server, inner-join

This is a valid SQL statement and working fine in SQL Server.

```
select classes.Id, classes.className, classes.Level, classes.timing
from classes
inner join StudentClasses on classes.Id = StudentClasses.classId;
```

It produces this result which is fine.

```
13  Trigonometry    Beginar     Morning
13  Trigonometry    Beginar     Morning
13  Trigonometry    Beginar     Morning
14  Maths           Advanced    Evening
15  Trigonometry    Advanced    Evening
```

Now I want to group them by classes.Id but it generates an error when I try to use group by as follows:

```
select classes.Id, classes.className, classes.Level, classes.timing
from classes
inner join StudentClasses on classes.Id = StudentClasses.classId
group by classes.Id;
```

This is the error I get:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Column 'classes.className' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to group by all the columns you have selected except aggregated ones. try the following.

If you have duplicates then you can use `distinct`.

```
select classes.Id, classes.className, classes.Level, classes.timing
from classes
inner join StudentClasses on classes.Id = StudentClasses.classId
group by classes.Id, classes.className, classes.Level, classes.timing 
;
```

Comment: Grouping by every column, with no aggregation, seems like an XY Problem here @Ahmad . If your grouping then you should have some kind of aggregation. If you're not aggregating, why are you using `GROUP BY`?